# How to set BackColor in a TextBox on Web form programmatically?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I want to set the backcolor of a web form programmatically at run time (so the user can select his or her preferred color).

I can do this with a named color, as in:

```
txt1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.PeachPuff;
```

but I am having a hard time figuring out how to set the color using the RGB value, as in:

```
txt1.BackColor = SomeConverter("#FEC200");
```

How is this done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this

```
txt1.BackColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#FEC200");
```

also, if you want to convert the `System.Drawing.Color` back to string(to save in db), do this:

```
private static String ConvertToHex(System.Drawing.Color color)
{
    return "#" + color.R.ToString("X2") + color.G.ToString("X2") + color.B.ToString("X2");
}

private static String ConvertToRGB(System.Drawing.Color color)
{
    return "RGB(" + color.R.ToString() + "," + color.G.ToString() + "," + color.B.ToString() + ")";
}
```

Comment: Look like same answer to me!

Comment: First person was deleted his/her answer.

Comment: there was definitely some other answer here, so i began to type, and when I posted, a same answer was already there, let me make this answer a little different thn :)

Comment: I recreated @Hossein-Narimani-Rad's original answer below.  There's obviously more than one way to skin a cat.

Comment: @Manish Mishra It is Ok. End of the day, we'are just trying to help each other. Have a great day fellows!

Answer (score 4):

```
txt1.BackColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#FEC200");
```

Answer (score 0):

There was another answer by @Hossein-Narimani-Rad that he deleted that said to use ColorConverter.ConvertFromString.  I tried it and got it to work like this:

```
System.Drawing.ColorConverter conv = new System.Drawing.ColorConverter();
txt1.BackColor = (System.Drawing.Color)conv.ConvertFromString("#FEC200");
```

But @Win 's and @Manish-Mishra 's answers are more concise and what I am going with.